# Javascript Replace Only if is exactly same

Tags: javascript

For example I have this string:

```
var string = 'attr:clase';
var new_string = string.replace(":clase",":class");
```

So the output is:

```
>> new_string = 'attr:class';
```

OKAY, till here is fine, but i have a problem, what happen if I have this string:

```
var string = 'attr:claseStatus';
var new_string = string.replace(":clase",":class");
```

My output now is:

```
>> new_string = 'attr:classStatus';
```

But i dont want it, i want this output:

```
>> new_string = 'attr:claseStatus';
```

I mean, i need only change if have the  exactly name, but if my string have some aditional text dont change, its like a case sensitive? or insensitve im not sure, i hope you can help me, thanks :S

-------- EDITED ----------

I have to say that ":clase" is  a string, so if you can tell me how i can change it to a reg expresion will be so usefull thanks you all:

```
x = ':clase';
y = somefunction(x);
y = /:clase$/;       //for example
```

Comment: `string.replace(/:clase$/,":class");`

Comment: how can i change a string -> ':clase'; to a regular expresion? -> /:clase/ , thanks!

Comment: use `RegExp(string)`

Comment: `x = ':clase' ; y = RegExp(x + '$');`

Comment: oh thanks!! and do know how i can add this ->> /:clase$/g <<- 'g'

Comment: because i have more lines and i need add global to this regexp

Comment: `RegExp(x + '$' , 'g')` , add it as second parameter

Comment: you so pro! thanks you so much! :)

Comment: I think you need to use word boundary match `\b`  `RegExp(x + '\\b' , 'g')`

Comment: `$` will only match at end of the string... in that case global flag have nothing to do with it

Answer (score 2):

What about using regular expressions and check for word ending

```
var new_string = string.replace(/:clase\b/,":class");
```

`\b` in regular expressions stands for end of word, so it will take :clase , but not :claseSomething

Answer (score 2):

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Use the $ to match the end of string with regular expression.

Comment: Example please :-) , also $ is not best solution here - if we will have string like foo:clase,bar:clase - or other variations like this, this won't work propertly